# "Accommodate" vs "accommodate to"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Searching on Google shows both forms:

- We will do our best to accommodate you.
- They accommodate to you and are very encouraging.

Sometimes they appear together in one sentence, thus makes me think that they actually have different meanings. I'm not sure though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accommodate has different meanings.
[Descriptions](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/accommodate)

I interpret your first sentence without any additional context as;

> to provide room for (someone) : to provide a place to stay and sleep
>   for (someone)

I interpret your second sentence (again) without any additional context as either;

> to make fit, suitable, or [congruous](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/congruous), harmonize, orient oneself, get on well with

or

> to do something helpful for (someone) : to provide what is needed or
>   wanted for (someone or something)

Anyway, I suggest you take a look at these definitions with more context.